# Conditional replacement of pandas cell values with cell vlaues from another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe pmov with columns SDRFT and DRFT containing float values. Some of the DRFT values are 0.0. When that happens, I want to replace the DRFT value with the SDRFT value.  For testing purposes, I've stored the rows where DRFT = 0.0 in dataframe df.

I've tried defining the function:

```
def SDRFT_is_DRFT(row):
    if row['SDRFT'] == row['DRFT']:
        pass
    elif row['SDRFT'] == 0:
        row['SDRFT'] = row['DRFT']
    elif ['DRFT'] == 0:
        row['DRFT'] = row['SDRFT']
    return row[['SDRFT','DRFT']]
```

and applying it with: `df.apply(SDRFT_is_DRFT, axis=1)`

which returns:

```
In []: df.apply(SDRFT_is_DRFT, axis=1)
Out[]: 
           SDRFT  DRFT
118    29.500000   0.0
144     0.000000   0.0
212    29.166667   0.0
250    21.000000   0.0
308    21.500000   0.0
317    24.500000   0.0
327    11.000000   0.0
334    31.000000   0.0
347    29.500000   0.0
348    35.000000   0.0
```

Which isn't the outcome I want.

I also tried the function:

```
def drft_repl(row):
    if row['DRFT']==0:
        row['DRFT'] = row['SDRFT']
```

which appeared to work for df.DRFT = df.apply(drft_repl, axis=1)

but `pmov.DRFT = pmov.apply(drft_repl, axis=1)` resulted in 100% replacement of DRFT values with SDRFT values, except where the DRFT value was nan.

How can I conditionally replace cell values in one column with values in another column of the same row?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.loc[df.DRFT == 0, 'DRFT'] = df.SDRFT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html). First is  replaced column `SDRFT` with values of `DRFT` where is condition `True` and last is replaced column `DRFT` with values of `SDRFT`:

```
pmov.SDRFT = pmov.SDRFT.mask(pmov.SDRFT == 0, pmov.DRFT)
pmov.DRFT = pmov.DRFT.mask(pmov.DRFT == 0, pmov.SDRFT)
print pmov  
         SDRFT       DRFT
118  29.500000  29.500000
144   0.000000   0.000000
212  29.166667  29.166667
250  21.000000  21.000000
308  21.500000  21.500000
317  24.500000  24.500000
327  11.000000  11.000000
334  31.000000  31.000000
347  29.500000  29.500000
348  35.000000  35.000000
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
pmov.loc[pmov.SDRFT == 0, 'SDRFT'] = pmov.DRFT 
pmov.loc[pmov.DRFT == 0, 'DRFT'] = pmov.SDRFT 
print pmov  
         SDRFT       DRFT
118  29.500000  29.500000
144   0.000000   0.000000
212  29.166667  29.166667
250  21.000000  21.000000
308  21.500000  21.500000
317  24.500000  24.500000
327  11.000000  11.000000
334  31.000000  31.000000
347  29.500000  29.500000
348  35.000000  35.000000
```

For better testing `DataFrame` was changed:

```
print pmov
     SDRFT   DRFT
118   29.5  29.50
144    0.0   5.98
212    0.0   7.30
250   21.0   0.00
308   21.5   0.00
317    0.0   0.00
327   11.0   0.00
334   31.0   0.00
347   29.5   0.00
348   35.0  35.00

pmov.SDRFT = pmov.SDRFT.mask(pmov.SDRFT == 0, pmov.DRFT)
pmov.DRFT = pmov.DRFT.mask(pmov.DRFT == 0, pmov.SDRFT)
print pmov 
     SDRFT   DRFT
118  29.50  29.50
144   5.98   5.98
212   7.30   7.30
250  21.00  21.00
308  21.50  21.50
317   0.00   0.00
327  11.00  11.00
334  31.00  31.00
347  29.50  29.50
348  35.00  35.00
```

```
pmov.loc[pmov.DRFT == 0, 'DRFT'] = pmov.SDRFT 
pmov.loc[pmov.SDRFT == 0, 'SDRFT'] = pmov.DRFT 
print pmov  
     SDRFT   DRFT
118  29.50  29.50
144   5.98   5.98
212   7.30   7.30
250  21.00  21.00
308  21.50  21.50
317   0.00   0.00
327  11.00  11.00
334  31.00  31.00
347  29.50  29.50
348  35.00  35.00
```

Comment: I tried MaxU's solution first, which worked and answered the question. this also appears to work and gives an alternative approach. Thanks to both!

Comment: I think his answer doesnt work, because if `0` values are in column `SDRFT`, there are no replaced. Try my second Dataframe for testing. His solution work only if no `0` values in column `SDRFT`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your second solution was: `pmov.loc[pmov.SDRFT == 0, 'SDRFT'] = pmov.DRFT` and `pmov.loc[pmov.DRFT == 0, 'DRFT'] = pmov.SDRFT`, which was more thorough than MaxU's, which as you point out was only doing the calculation one way. I made the appropriate substitutions from MaxU's answer to calculate in the other direction, which resulted in your solution. Again, thanks!